How to download and save a m3u8 HLS livestream to mp4 using JavaScript (client side)?
I am using React (typescript) and I want to download m3u8 HLS livestream as a single mp4 video. How can I achieve this.
I am providing a sample m3u8 file below:
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://example.com/api/hlskey?videoKey=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&key=enc.key"
#EXTINF:6.000000,
000.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
001.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
002.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
003.ts
#EXTINF:5.766667,
004.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
005.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
006.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
007.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
008.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
009.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
010.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
011.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
012.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
013.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
014.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
015.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
016.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
017.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
018.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
019.ts
#EXTINF:5.566667,
020.ts
#EXTINF:4.500000,
021.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
022.ts
#EXTINF:1.600000,
023.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

I have tried to do this using @ffmpeg/ffmpeg but it did not work. Please suggest a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

(1) Don't practice with AES encrypted videos. If you don't know how to download livestream into MP4, then start with a simple test stream until you get it right. (2) FFmpeg was your best "easy" chance. If that one is not working (eg: it did not install? it gives error messages?) then you will have to learn about MP4 structure and write your own muxer (copy byte values from TS and put into some output MP4 bytes array)

Your "How can I achieve this" must focus on whether you want help to fix your code that talks to FFmpeg, or else, you want help to write your own muxer?

@VC.One I want to write my own muxer. You can also do it using ffmpeg, but in my case it did not work for me. May be I was not able to write the code correctly.
